# List-comprehension evaluation

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I don't understand why below 2 case be different ? because of lazy evaluation?

1)

```
Main> [x:xs | x:xs <- tails [1,2,3]]
=> [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3]]
```

2)

```
Main> [x:xs | x:xs' <- tails [1,2,3], x':xs <- tails [1,2,3]]
=> [[1,2,3],[1,3],[1], [2,2,3],[2,3],[2],[3,2,3],[3,3],[3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

They are different by definition. The best way to show this, is an example. List comprehensions try to find all possible sets of variables, that can be choosed from the list without violating the condition. If you have more than one variable, it returns each combination of them. For instance:

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [1,2,3]]
```

yields:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

What can we see? First, an element of the first list is chosen, than one of the second list. The result is a list of *all possible ways of choosing x and y*.

SO your second statement must of course yield the second result.

Comment: list source are different? case 1's source is one, case 2's source is two.

Comment: @runnerhigh: What do you mean? Haskell doesn't cares about whether the lists are equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing to do with lazy evaluation.

Consider this third case:

```
Prelude Data.List> [x:xs | x:xs' <- tails [1,2,3], x':xs <- tails [1,2,3], x == x']
[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it:

```
ghci> :m +Data.List
ghci> :m +Control.Applicative
ghci> let l1 = [x | x:xs <- tails [1,2,3]]
ghci> l1
[1,2,3]
ghci> let l2 = [xs | x:xs <- tails [1,2,3]]
ghci> l2
[[2,3],[3],[]]
```

Your first comprehension draws `x` and `xs` as a "pair", sort of keeping them "zipped" together.

```
ghci> zipWith (:) l1 l2
[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

Your second comprehension draws all combinations of `x` and `xs`, combining them with `(:)`.

```
ghci> (:) <$> l1 <*> l2
[[1,2,3],[1,3],[1],[2,2,3],[2,3],[2],[3,2,3],[3,3],[3]]
```